# Ionic/Cordova not using camera but apple requires permission

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying to upload a new version of my app, to App Store, but it was rejected because:

> This app attempts to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description. The app's Info.plist must contain an NSCameraUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data.

But my app do not need to access the camera. I already looked into plugins list (`ionic plugin list`) but there is no plugin for camera access.

This is part of my config.xml

```
<preference name="loadUrlTimeoutValue" value="3600000"/>
  <preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="false" />
  <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false"/>
  <preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false"/>
  <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true"/>
  <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="15"/>
  <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none"/>
  <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen"/>
  <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="4000"/>
  <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none"/>
  <preference name="orientation" value="portrait"/>
  <preference name="KeyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction" value="false"/>
  <preference name="exit-on-suspend" value="false"/>
  <feature name="Keyboard">
    <param name="ios-package" onload="true" value="IonicKeyboard"/>
  </feature>
  <feature name="StatusBar">
    <param name="ios-package" onload="true" value="CDVStatusBar"/>
  </feature>
  <plugin name="cordova-sqlite-storage" spec="~0.7.14"/>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-app-version" spec="~0.1.8"/>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-network-information" spec="~1.2.0"/>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-insomnia" spec="https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Insomnia-PhoneGap-Plugin.git"/>
  <plugin name="com.testfairy.cordova-plugin" spec="https://github.com/testfairy/testfairy-cordova-plugin"/>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-datepicker" spec="https://github.com/VitaliiBlagodir/cordova-plugin-datepicker.git"/>
  <plugin name="onesignal-cordova-plugin" spec="~1.12.5"/>
  <plugin name="de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification" spec="https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications.git"/>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-background-mode" spec="https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode.git"/>
```

Anyone could help ?

Comment: Can you share your `config.xml`?

Comment: Sure @Phonolog, i have updated my question with this information

Comment: Is it possible that the TestFairy plugin has a screen capture or camera feature that you are not aware of and are not using?

Answer (score 0):

You may have  a plugin that has camera functionality that you are not using, but it is still part of the plugin. You also may have a plugin that has been installed previously but is not in your `config.xml` file. You can try the following:

#### Reset State

You can run `ionic state restore` to have Ionic restore the app to the saved parameters. This will re-install the plugins added via the CLI with the `--save` tag or ones you have manually added to the `package.json` file. This may clear up some residual code issues.

#### Add Description

You can just add the tag that Apple wants to see. You can add the tag using [cordova-custom-config](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-custom-config#config-blocks) to edit your `-Info.plist` via your `config.xml` file. You should be able to add the following to `config.xml` to satisfy Apple:

```
<config-file platform="ios" target="*-Info.plist" parent="NSCameraUsageDescription">
  <string>Because racecar</string>
</config-file>
```